# Android Studio behind the proxy

Tags: android, flutter, jcenter

I know this type of questions is around since many years and I tried each and every solution with no luck.

I am trying to setup development environment with Android Studio with Flutter. I am keep getting error regarding the certificate.

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I tried to change **https** to **http** in the **gradle** prop file and also tried to change from jcenter() to maven but it is not working. Also I tried to import the certificate using the **KeyStore Explorer**, it says successfully imported but throwing same error when I am trying to run the project.

> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.pom'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.11.
>        Required by:
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.3.0
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.3.0
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.3.0
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.3.0
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.3.0
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0 > com.android.tools:common:26.3.0
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.3.0
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.3.0
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.3.0 > com.android.tools:repository:26.3.0
>   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.11.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.11.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.11.pom'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0.

I talked with my admin team and they are asking for which URLs they need to white list in order to make the flutter work. Let me know if you know what to be white listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're behind a proxy at work, your Server Team may be blocking certain file types.
That's the case for me as I don't have any of these issues when working from an outside line.

Try copying and pasting the link into a browser and look at the error message.

Alternatively, you could try emailing your Server Team and have them open it up for you (temporarily).

Comment: I can access each URL using browser without any issue. Is there any way where I can download all this manually and put it somewhere? It looks like the Android Studio is having issue with certificates..

Comment: Downloading them manually and storing them is probably a tedious yet doable task, but if you're living the same life as me, it will be a reoccurring issue for you so that's not ideal.
You should try to identify the source of this problem. Can you try on an outside line or make an exception in the firewall?

Comment: Today I am going to talk with my network team but what should I ask them to do? I am able to access the same URL from the browser but when my Android Studio tries to do so it fails because of certificates..

Comment: My Windows team has given me the self signed certificates that I imported in Android studio -> settings -> certificates... But it is still not working

Comment: if you can tell me where should I put the dependencies then I can download them in the unrestricted network and then simply copy paste them in my computer here behind the proxy.

Comment: Downloading them and moving them to whatever folder they need to go in is beyond me, and for good reason. I never explored that option because this is going to be a repetitive exercise while working behind a firewall.

Comment: Your best bet for now is either 1) take your machine and plug it into a LAN on the unrestricted network and do your work there (get everything download). 2) have your Network team watch your traffic for any exceptions/blocked requests, and then open it up temporarily while you do your work. They can close back up once you're done.

Comment: I talked with my admin team and they are asking the for all the URLS that needs to be white listed. How can I find them? is it https://pub.dev?

Comment: Just give them the highest level of each URL you're getting hit with.  It may take a few back and forths before you get all the ones you need. ie: https://jcenter.bintray.com

Comment: Talked with network team and they unblock some of the URLs. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I knew the pain you were going through. Glad I could help.